# EC2 instances not being joined to ECS cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

My EC2 instances are not being shown on ECS cluster but they are appearing on EC2 console. This issue occurs when I specify a different ubuntu image rather than default Amazon image.

Providing the ecs-cli command I used below

```
ecs-cli up --keypair emaile --capability-iam --size 2 --instance-type t2.medium --launch-type EC2 --image-id ami-03f0fd1a2ba530e75 --cluster-config ec2-cluster --ecs-profile ecs-profile --port 8000
```

I checked the instances user data and providing you the same

```
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="d9c7ec8c5709925e324f39982c69c71d86d39ec660280837e8a5e69e93c2"
MIME-Version: 1.0

--d9c7ec8c5709925e324f39982c69c71d86d39ec660280837e8a5e69e93c2
Content-Type: text/text/plain; charset="utf-8"
Mime-Version: 1.0

#!/bin/bash
echo ECS_CLUSTER=ec2-cluster >> /etc/ecs/ecs.config

--d9c7ec8c5709925e324f39982c69c71d86d39ec660280837e8a5e69e93c2--
```

Whenever I try ecs-cli compose up getting the below error

```
ERRO[0000] Error running tasks                           error="InvalidParameterException: No Container Instances were found in your cluster." task definition=0xc00033e5a0
FATA[0000] InvalidParameterException: No Container Instances were found in your cluster
```

I think the issue is reproducible, Thanks for help in advance

**edit**:

Instance final log error

```
[   22.043805] cloud-init[1555]: Cloud-init v. 20.2-45-g5f7825e2-0ubuntu1~18.04.1 finished at Sat, 07 Nov 2020 10:04:16 +0000. Datasource DataSourceEc2Local.  Up 22.03 seconds

[[0;1;31mFAILED[0m] Failed to start Execute cloud user/final scripts.

See 'systemctl status cloud-final.service' for details.

[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target Cloud-init target.
```

Comment: Does this `multipart/mixed` work correctly? Can you ssh to the instance and verify?

Comment: @Marcin I SSH into the instance but cannot find /etc/ecs/ directory. when I don't specify any machine image the default amazon linux image working fine.

Comment: Why do you use `multipart/mixed` for your user data? This is rather a hack and rarely used. Why not create regular user-data?

Comment: @Marcin I didn't provide any multipart/mixed  user data it is generated by default. I want to specify a ubuntu 18.04 ami. I added a edit showing instance system log.

Comment: ubutu 18.04 is not EBS optimized. To use it you have to setup it up from scratch. Its much more then just using `echo ECS_CLUSTER`. So have you set it up like this?

Comment: I didn't set it up like that. I didn't provide any user arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 18.04 is not on the [list of ECS-optimized](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-optimized_AMI.html) AMIs. The list only includes AMIs based on Amazon Linux 1, Amazon Linux 2 and Windows.

If you want to use ubuntu, you have set it up yourself to be able to work with ECS. There are some tutorials on how to do it. One example is [here](https://blog.tedivm.com/rants/2020/07/aws-ecs-with-ubuntu-and-gpu-support/).

Comment: It's not working @Markin. I don't know how to solve it but your answer was useful.